# Scraping R error "stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 59, 165, 89"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Some of the rows have multiple sub rows, and I'm not sure how to address this. This is my simple scraper so far in R:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://www.slga.com/permits-and-licences/cannabis-permits/cannabis-retailing/cannabis-retailers-in-saskatchewan"
ssk_page = read_html(link)

Province = "Saskatchewan"
City = page %>% html_nodes("h1 a") %>% html_text()
Name = page %>% html_nodes("h3 , h3 a") %>% html_text()
Address = page %>% html_nodes("/html/body/main/div/div/section/p") %>% html_text()

SaskatchewanPR = data.frame(Province, City, Name, Address, Date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This code was being run with no problem until it got to the address section, as some stores have multiple locations saved as such:
[image]

This is the error I receive:

```
> library(rvest)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> link = "https://www.slga.com/permits-and-licences/cannabis-permits/cannabis-retailing/cannabis-retailers-in-saskatchewan"
> page = read_html(link)
> 
> Province = "Saskatchewan"
> City = page %>% html_nodes("h1 a") %>% html_text()
> Name = page %>% html_nodes("h3 , h3 a") %>% html_text()
> Address = page %>% html_nodes("h3+ p") %>% html_text()
> Date = Sys.Date()
> 
> SaskatchewanPR = data.frame(Province, City, Name, Address, Date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in data.frame(Province, City, Name, Address, Date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 59, 165, 89
```

Comment: The html is deceptively irregular. Is there an alternative source for the data?

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to work with this website as it constantly updates and is accurate.